# Are perfection, morality, sanity and beauty "absolute"?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, metaethics, belief

**Are perfection/morality/sanity/beauty.. absolute terms**?

**Perfection**. I am told its a self evident term and cannot be defined. Anyway I had a conversation with a person who tried to prove the existence if God by showing that **Universe is perfectly created**. I am of the view that perfection is relative for our minds are designed to perceive something perfect and something defective. Can I be proven to be wrong if I deviate from the usual perfection?

**Morality(Good vs Evil)**  There are many actions which are universally classified as good and evil. But, if someone does not, can it be shown to him that such and such deeds are moral and so and so are evil. Consider the case if his thinking is completely opposite. For instance how can it be reasoned **why killing/raping... acts**

**Sanity** Is sanity absolute? To psychopaths, we are abnormal and vice versa. How can abnormality/normality be reasoned?. What if the no of abnormals become greater than the no of so called normals in the world and they become power? Would it alter the standards of sanity/insanity?

**Beauty(non living)** Is beauty absolute? For living it can easily be shown to be relative, for example to me my gf is the most beautiful, to you yours. Lets consider the case of non living(taste/smell/flowers/natural scenes...). What if I say(to me) that the most delicious food has a bad taste,the most elegant fragrance gives a bad odour, rose,natural scenes  doesn't seem to be beautiful at all. Can I be disproven. (Just don't say that a lot of peaple thinks otherwise,so you are wrong)

PS **I am totally knew to philosophy, I am sorry if my ignorance is borderline offensive. These are just my thoughts, I haven't studied anything philosophical**.

Comment: I doubt that this makes sense as **one** question. The answer on whether sanity is absolute will be an entirely different one than the one on whether beauty is. Can you please split these and deal with them one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Tom! As far as I know, there are no such thing as "absolute concepts." We do have absolute propositions and statements which involve a concept predicated upon a subject in an absolute way.

So absoluteness in logic must be a property of an act of predication not of concepts per se. God's attributes are examples of absolute predications. e.g. God is all-powerful.

Another example would be 2+2=4 which is an absolute statement, that is, always true.

Comment: @ infatuated I agree with you as long as its maths..otherwise no absolutes!

Comment: @ infatuated Please don't involve **God's existence and His** attributes for his very existence can't be proven logically. There are always counter arguments.(though I believe He exists)

Comment: Math or other logically valid/substantiated absolute statements.

Comment: Don't bother! You can only take that as an example for now!

Comment: @ infatuated What do you mean by other logically valid/substantiated absolute statements?

Comment: Any logically valid/substantiated absolute statement! I'm just arguing for the possibility of such statements!

Comment: @ infatuated For instance?

Comment: @TomLynd 
Didn't I provide examples in my answer?

Comment: Please continue the discussion in chat